# Multithreading implementation - pro and cons between java and C

Tags: java, c, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a task to extend an implementation of an ongoing project written in C that is already working well, so that it will be multi-threaded.

I have many years of experience with Java, but very limited for C. So basically I have some options like the following:

1. Rewrite all of the code to Java and later implement multi-threading in Java
2. Implement multi-threading in Java by calling some methods from C library through JNI
3. Learn C and continue the task in C.

By considering that the multi-threaded version does not have to get the latest update from the C library, and probably later I might need to put these code in some big data framework like Hadoop.

In order to find out which option could be better for me, I would need comments about the following questions based on what you have already experienced before.

- How smooth it will be to call a C function from Java and if there is any significant limitation?
- What are the pro and cons of implementing multi-threading in C?

And also which option that you think is better?

Comment: I would go for 1.  And I'm sure there are people who would vote for 3 as well.  But we cannot tell you which is the better choice FOR YOU.

Comment: Note that the current C code is not necessarily thread safe, so option 2 may be a bit more work than just creating a JNI interface.

Comment: @StephenC it's a bioinformatics algorithm for clustering. Mostly related to calculations.

Comment: `many years of experience with Java, but very limited for C, furthermore  it's a bioinformatics algorithm for clustering`: don't go for `3.`, `an ongoing project written in C that is already working well`, if it ain't broke, don't fix it, don't go for `1.`

Comment: @dresden What are the pro and cons of implementing multi-threading in C? In what c environment are you working in?

Comment: @dresden - That doesn't help.  How good are you at C? Java?  How good at multi-threading?  Debugging? How much does performance really matter?  Who is paying for the software development (e.g. your salary, scholarship, etc) ... and what do >>they<< think about the time and money for the software development versus performance versus deadlines?  WE can't answer these things, but they are what YOU should be taking into account!!

Answer (score 2):

I would go on 3. Multithreading relies on few basic concepts of mutex and semaphores, both in the POSIX standard, and I would recommend you learning them. The C concepts are really basic, the most difficult thing you have to learn will probably be pointers so nothing hard. Having coded multithread projects both in Java and in C I would recommend C (having an hard Java background it's difficult to say for me! ) to learn an important part of POSIX standard (used in Unix too), not to depend on extern libraries and virtual machines. If you want to do it in Java, I would exclude solution 2 and make a standalone Java project, it has appropriate libraries to support multithreading.